# git-svn rebase "File name too long"

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, dvcs

I'm running

```
$ git svn rebase
```

After couple of minutes it's finished fetching and started rebasing.
And I have got next error message:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: cannot stat '$73_chars_4_deep_levels_path_with_spaces/$180_chars_file_name_looks_cutted_with_spaces_too': File name too long
error: cannot stat '$73_chars_4_deep_levels_path_with_spaces/$180_chars_file_name_looks_cutted_with_spaces_too': File name too long
error: cannot stat '$73_chars_4_deep_levels_path_with_spaces/$180_chars_file_name_looks_cutted_with_spaces_too': File name too long
could not detach HEAD
rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

I read the following question
"[git checkout-index: unable to create file (File name too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114301/git-checkout-index-unable-to-create-file-file-name-too-long)"

It is closely relative to me, but doesn't solving my problem.

Nor

```
git ls-files --stage
```

nor

```
git ls-files
```

doesn't found problem "$180_chars_file_name_looks_cutted_with_spaces_too" file.
Also I can't rename files (by some kind of politic decisions) as said by bdonlan in his solution.

Is there are any workarounds or solutions except download each folder to separate SVN-repo and merge through grafts?

**UPDATE**

I have tried all of above at

```
MacOsX 10.6
git version 1.7.9.6
svn, version 1.7.4 (r1295709)
```

And commiters are doing they job from Windows with NTFS

**UPDATE 2**

I did some research.
I think the problem lies in UTF-8 chars.
I've tried to create new file

```
$ touch "$180_chars_file_name_looks_cutted_with_spaces_too"
$ ls
132_chars_file_name_with_numbers_at_the_end
```

File looks corrupted. It has some numbers at the end. You may reproduce it, for example:

```
$ touch "яяяяяяяяя яя яяяя яя яяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяя я яяяяяя я яяя яяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя я яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяя яя яяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя яяяяя яяяяяя я яяя яяяяя яяя"
$ ls
яяяяяяяяя яя яяяя яя яяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяя я яяяяяя я яяя яяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя я яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяя яя яяяяяя яяяя#464CDD8
```

When successfully opened "132_chars_file_name_with_numbers_at_the_end" by vim editor and edited it.
But when I entered ":wq" file disappeared.

Now I think I found the root of my problem, but life doesn't going easier after that )

Comment: what's your platform and git version?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to write.
MacOsX 10.6
git version 1.7.9.6
svn, version 1.7.4 (r1295709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found as elegant solution as possible in my situation.
I have created ExFat dmg-image by MacOs Disk utility.
After that I mounted new image-file and copied my git-repo into it.
It works more better than Cygwin under VirtualBox.

Also, I've tried to use NTFS, but I have taken fiasco. Nor NTFS-3G, nor Tuxero driver doesn't support long UTF-names.
The same story with Linux and ReiserFS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one terrible but working workaround that I found.

MsysGit and Cygwin are both operates with that files normally.

So, I got VirtualBox and installed Windows with [MSysGit-utf8](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit-utf8/downloads/list) into it.

Then I copied my project into VirtualBox.

**git svn rebase** did it's work like a charm.

After that I became able to copy updated project (or rebase from it) back to MacOs host.
Of course, files with long name did not copied, but I can skip them now and add to ignore list.