# MacOsX HFS+ corrupts long utf-8 filenames by adding hash sign and number at the end

Tags: macos, file-io, utf-8, long-filenames, hfs+

I'm user of MacOsX 10.6.
Some time ago I found that [I can't fetch git changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281072/git-svn-rebase-file-name-too-long).

I did some research and I think the problem lies in UTF-8 chars. I've tried to create new file

```
$ touch "$180_utf-8_chars_file_name_with_spaces"
$ ls
132_chars_file_name_with_numbers_at_the_end
```

File looks corrupted. It has some numbers at the end. You may reproduce it, for example:

```
$ touch "яяяяяяяяя яя яяяя яя яяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяя я яяяяяя я яяя яяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя я яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяя яя яяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя яяяяя яяяяяя я яяя яяяяя яяя"
$ ls
яяяяяяяяя яя яяяя яя яяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяя я яяяяяя я яяя яяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяяяя я яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя яяяяяя яя яяяяяя яяяя#464CDD8
```

When I successfully opened "132_chars_file_name_with_numbers_at_the_end" by vim editor and edited it.
But when I entered ":wq" file disappeared.

Is there are some workarounds? How can I fix it?

Comment: I've posted the solution in the [related question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281072/git-svn-rebase-file-name-too-long