# How to force `git merge`?

Tags: git

I'm experiencing the "file name too long" error described [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114301/git-checkout-index-unable-to-create-file-file-name-too-long).  I've already fixed the file name in a remote repo, and now I'm trying to merge in the changes from the remote that fix the name.  However, git won't let me merge because it thinks I have uncommitted changes (the too-long-named file it can't create).  Is there some way to force git to merge?  Note that `git status` lists no modifications, besides printing the file name too long error, so I don't see how to satisfy git first locally.  In particular, git does *not* report the file as rm'd or missing.

Comment: First `git fetch` then try: `git update-ref <branch> <remote>/<branch>`

Comment: @OpDeCirkel: that command seems to be a no-op for me.  I also tried `git update-ref --no-deref <branch> <remote>/<branch>`. (The fix below already worked, and git won't let me `reset --hard` back to the messed up commit, but I am able to branch to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by doing a `git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>`.