# Git "File name too long" after /home encryption with eCryptfs on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, encryption, ecryptfs

Basically after doing /home directory encryption with eCryptfs because of required security reasons of my client now when I tried to pull latest master I received such error: 
"filename" File name too long. The file is actually missing now and if I proceed to commit it will disappear (as deleted). As I understood the reason is file name limitation (143 characters start requiring >255 characters to encrypt) of the encryption. The question is is there any way to workaround that? The file name is really long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git checkout-index: unable to create file (File name too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114301/git-checkout-index-unable-to-create-file-file-name-too-long)

Comment: Checkout the repository outside of encrypted home.